# jython wasadmin script gives com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConfigServiceException

Tags: ibm-was

I was having difficulty in running jython wsadmin script. Following error happens when i try to invoke "AdminConfig.save()" in the script. Its was able to install the application successfully but when it tries the save the configuration, it gives following error.

`[exec] ADMA5017I: Uninstallation of TestApp started.
     [exec] ADMA5104I: The server index entry for WebSphere:cell=WASD01VWNode04Cell,node=WASD01VWNode04 is updated successfully.
     [exec] ADMA5102I: The configuration data for IEApp from the configuration repository is deleted successfully.
     [exec] ADMA5011I: The cleanup of the temp directory for application IEApp is complete.
     [exec] ADMA5106I: Application TestApp uninstalled successfully.
     [exec] ADMA5016I: Installation of TestApp started.
     [exec] ADMA5058I: Application and module versions are validated with versions of deployment targets.
     [exec] ADMA5005I: The application TestApp is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
     [exec] ADMA5005I: The application TestApp is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
     [exec] ADMA5081I: The bootstrap address for client module is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
     [exec] ADMA5053I: The library references for the installed optional package are created.
     [exec] ADMA5005I: The application TestApp is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
     [exec] ADMA5005I: The application TestApp is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
     [exec] SECJ0400I: Successfully updated the application TestApp with the appContextIDForSecurity information.
     [exec] ADMA5005I: The application TestApp is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
     [exec] ADMA5005I: The application TestApp is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
     [exec] ADMA5113I: Activation plan created successfully.
     [exec] ADMA5011I: The cleanup of the temp directory for application IEApp is complete.
     [exec] ADMA5013I: Application TestApp installed successfully.
     [exec] WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "mywasadmin.py"; exception information: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConfigServiceException
     [exec] com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException
     [exec] org.apache.soap.SOAPException: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Read timed out; targetException=java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out]
     [exec] 
     [exec] WASX7341W: No "save" was performed before the interactive scripting session exited; configuration changes will not be saved`

We are using WebSphere application  8.5.0 version. This is a standalone instance.

I also increased soap timeout parameter(com.ibm.SOAP.requestTimeout=4000) in the WAS application server /properties/soap.client.prop. But its of no use.

Any thoughts on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in ibm documentation this usually occurs on computer servers that are overloaded.

- Perform the following steps:  Increase the value of
  com.ibm.SOAP.requestTimeout in soap.client.props
  (/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/properties/soap.client.props)
- Run the script to cleanup (cleanupWAS.sh )
- Run the deployment script (setupWAS.sh)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Websphere throws a `com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConfigServiceException` in a shared environment with multiple administrative users if two users attempt concurrent updates of the same WebSphere Application Server configuration document.
Check the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rrun_app_config_conflicts.html) to manage the conflict.

Normally, trying again will deploy the application just fine unless another conflict occurs.